# How do I download an file(image) in a folder on my Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I have some files (images) in a folder on my Ubuntu server. I want a link like `http://ip...../image.png`. Is there a way to do this? I have the server's IP address. All directions and solutions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to access the files over HTTP then you need to setup a webserver.

If you want to simply download the files really quick, the fastest way is to go into the directory you want to download and run

```
python3 -m http.server
```

This will make your files accessible at http://ip_of_server:8080/.

If you however intend to make the files accessible for a large amount of people, you will want to install a dedicated webserver such as for example [apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) or [nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04). These will allow full customisation such as for example password protecting files/directories.

Comment: Do you have any specific instructions to install and run? I am new and I programming for android does not know much about webserver. Thank you so much

Comment: I included links to detailled setup instructions in my answer, simply click on either apache or nginx.